# Can I delete C:\ProgramData\Dell\SARemediation\SystemRepair?

Tags: windows, disk-space

After running Spacesniffer on my Dell G3, I noticed a huge 14 gigabyte folder whose path was C:\ProgramData\Dell\SARemediation\SystemRepair. What does it do, and can I delete it?

Comment: https://www.dell.com/community/forums/forumtopicprintpage/board-id/supportassist-pcs/message-id/91093/print-single-message/true/page/1

Comment: I saw two different views:  one that it was an important data file for dell processing and one that it could be deleted: https://www.dell.com/community/SupportAssist-for-PCs/Dell-SupportAssist-created-backup/td-p/7700249/page/3   I added some information to my answer

Comment: The Dell programs aren't required for a healthy PC.  On the other hand, they will notify you of suggested driver updates and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program Data is what it says:  Data for program applications.

Generally you can delete files in Program Data.

I suggest you move the file to a USB Drive (so not truly delete it), then restart the machine and test for proper operation.

You can always move it back it need be.

For Dell, you can uninstall Support Assist and that will delete the folder.

I checked my own Program Data folder and it is only 10 GB in total, so nothing that big.

Here is a Dell thread for that file.

[Dell SAR folder](https://www.dell.com/community/SupportAssist-for-PCs/Dell-SupportAssist-created-backup/td-p/7700249/page/3)

> I found the program "Dell Support Assist Remediation" in the Windows
> (Settings > Apps) and uninstalled it. That deleted this backup folder
> and gave me my memory back. Hopefully that'll also solve the problem
> of "backing up" my files without my consent.